# migrating Plone site gives error 'specified module CMFPlone.AccessRule not found'

Tags: plone

I am moving an old Plone site (3.1.6) to another server running Plone 4.

I have copied over the Data.fs file to the new plone environment. However, the the new site is giving the following message:

> An error was encountered while publishing this resource.
>
> Error Type: NotFound
>
> Error Value: The specified module, 'CMFPlone.accessRule', couldn't be found.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone [here](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/CMFPlone-AccessRule-not-found-Plone-3-3-5-gt-4-0-upgrade-Windows-td5494048.html) solved exactly the same error by copying the `Extensions` directory from an old version of Products.CMFPlone (you can find that dir into your source buildout or directly from [the code repository](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/zipball/3.1-rc1)) into the corresponding product in your new buildout. There is already a pending a ticket for this ([#11146](http://dev.plone.org/ticket/11146))